# Ошибка запуска Is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Есть виртуалка на базе Vmware с Windows 7. В ней прикручена папка с основной машины как сетевой диск по адресу *Z:\Work\Program\Test\Test.exe*

Часто виртуалку приостанавливаю на паузу/снова запускаю. После запуска если открыть окно Run (Win + R) и вставить туда путь *Z:\Work\Program\Test\Test.exe* и запустить, может запуститься, а может появиться ошибка *"Z:\Work\Program\Test\Test.exe is not a valid Win32 application"*.

Если появляется ошибка, проблему можно обойти следующими способами:

1. Через мой компьютер дошагать до файла в папке и запустить его, запуск всегда успешный.
2. Если вначале запустить в Run (Win + R) папку *Z:\Work\Program\Test*, то откроется проводник с этой папкой. После этого повторно выполнить в Run (Win + R) уже файл *Z:\Work\Program\Test\Test.exe*, запуск тоже всегда успешный.

Как сделать так чтобы всегда с первой попытки запуск происходил без сбоев? И почему он собственно говоря происходит?

P.S. Нужно для того чтобы приложение на c# запускало этот файл. Но ошибка в данном случае та же, что и например в окне Run.

Comment: Здесь уместно добавить тег [tag:windows], т.к. специалисты по [tag:c#] и [tag:winapi] не обязательно любят разбираться в ее капризульках.

Answer (score 1):

Дело скорее всего в том что из-за останова отваливается сетевой диск. Когда вы пытаетесь перейти в папку, происходит повторная попытка подключения (успешная, возможно вам незаметная). Я бы попробовал создать локальный файл на диске виртуалки, который собственно ваши действия будет повторять: сначала перемонтировать диск (`net use`), а потом уже запускать программу.